# Android japanese with romaji inputs

Tags: keyboard, languages, input-methods

On PC, you have your standard romaji keyboard, and when you enter "ka" it automatically converts it to the corresponding character, instead of having straight hiragana keys.

Can one do that on Android ?

Answer (score 2):

Found it. It's possible by installing [Google Japanese Input](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.inputmethod.japanese) app. Switch keyboard to QWERTY in the settings.